# How do you change the namspace of a vb.net form with a VS designer partial class?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have some forms in my program that I created with the designer. Right now all my classes are in the default root namespace. I would like to split up the program a little more and move some of the classes to sub namespaces. For non gui classes it is easy I just surround the class definition with a,

```
Namespace defualtNameSpace.XXXX

...

End Namespace
```

But for classes with partial class definitions created by the designer I am not sure what to do. I heard that you should not edit designer created code but I know of no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `namespace` in the designer file e.g. `Form1.Designer.cs`.   As long as you do not change the code within the **Windows Form Designer generated code** `region`, you should be fine.

Another option is to create another folder in your solution.  After adding a form to the new folder, its `namespace` will automatically have the name of the folder appended to it.

Comment: My part of the class is defined in another code file but as you pointed out I can't change the namespace of only one part. I want to know if there is a better way to change the namespace of the designer generated code then to manual change the code.

Comment: I have modified my answer to be more relevant :)